# Django/Dropbox uploaded file is 0 bytes

Tags: python, django, dropbox-api

I **CAN'T** figure out why my uploaded file to Dropbox via Django is always zero bytes.

Outsize Django (using raw Python), the files get uploaded normally.

My HTML has `enctype="multipart/form-data"` declared.

**VIEWS.PY:**

```
if cv_form.is_valid():
   cv_form.save(commit=True)

   # print(request.FILES['cv'].size) == 125898
   DOC = request.FILES['cv']
   PATH = f'/CV/{DOC}'
   upload_handler(DOC, PATH)

   #http_response_happens_here()
```

**HANDLER:**

```
def upload_handler(DOC, PATH):
    dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(settings.DROPBOX_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN)
    dbx.files_upload(DOC.file.read(), PATH) 

    #file gets uploaded but always 0bytes in size
```

Answer (score -1):

My bad! How did I not see it.

The solution incase anyone else runs into the same issue. Battled it for a while myself.

```
if cv_form.is_valid():
   cv_form.save(commit=False) # commit should be False before upload

   # print(request.FILES['cv'].size) == 125898
   DOC = request.FILES['cv']
   PATH = f'/CV/{DOC}'
   upload_handler(DOC, PATH)
   cv_form.save(commit=True) # now you can save the file.

   #http_response_happens_here()
```